# data cleaning using R

Tags: r

I have a variable named `NCM` and this a numeric question. So those who answer >= 3 I need to clear the data at the variable `Mbrand` and the cleaned data should be stored in a new dataframe. Hence I tried using the function `filter` unfortunately i got an error "no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "list"". Hence I request to let me know if any alternate methods are available in R - as i am new to R.

Here is the data.

```
NCM <- c(5,1,3,2,4)
Mbrand <- c(1,5,3,4,2)
data <- data.frame(NCM,Mbrand)

data$Mbrand <- factor(data$Mbrand, levels = c(1,5,3,4,2),
   labels = c("Brand1", "Brand5", "Brand3", "Brand4", "Brand2"))
```

Finally the output should be

```
NCM Mbrand

5   Brand1

1   

3   Brand3

2   

4   Brand2
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is to replace some values in 'Mbrand' based on the condition in 'NCM', we could change it to 'NA' as it is easier for subsetting with `is.na/na.omit/complete.cases` etc.

```
is.na(data$Mbrand) <- data$NCM <3
```

Or

```
data$Mbrand[data$NCM<3] <- NA
```

If we need to replace the values with `''`, then we have to either convert to 'character' class or include `''` as a 'level' in the 'Mbrand' before changing the values to `''`.

```
levels(data$Mbrand) <- c(levels(data$Mbrand), '')
data$Mbrand[data$NCM<3] <- ''
```

#### Update

If you need to `subset` the dataset based on the condition

```
data1 <- subset(data, NCM>=3)
```

Or if you need the whole dataset to be stored as a different object after replacing the values, just assign it to a different object

```
data2 <- data1
data2$Mbrand[data2$NCM<3] <- NA
data2
```

Comment: thanks for the syntax its working well. however i need to store the data in a new data frame after doing these data cleaning...

Comment: @Jagadish Your expected result showed both the cases.  it was not mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

That is the quickest way I can think of:

```
NCM <- c(5,1,3,2,4)
Mbrand <- c(1,5,3,4,2)
fac<-factor(Mbrand, levels = c(1,5,3,4,2,''),
            labels = c("Brand1", "Brand5", "Brand3", "Brand4", "Brand2", '')) 


data<-data.frame(NCM, Mbrand=ifelse(NCM>=3, fac, ''))
```